# disabled NIC on 17.10 - now can't get NIC enabled

Tags: networking, virtualization, nic

I'm an Ubuntu N00b and to be "extra secure" I decided to disable my NIC (on a virtual machine version of Ubunti 17.10)
I did quite a bit of searching and trying stuff out with the network adapters before posting here, so I may have made things worse.

Any ideas how I can get my internet and NIC working again?
Below are the outcomes from running

```
$ ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens38: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:65:76:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: You should be able to re-enable the network in the same setting at the virtualization software you're using and, by the way, should have been mentioned in the question. Please [edit] and include that information along with an accurate description of what you did to disable it.

Comment: @MichaelBay - I disabled teh IC by disabling the network connection in the Ubunto GUI.  I can't now see it to re-enable it

Comment: Open system settings > network and re-enable.

Comment: when i go to system settings > network I only have an option for VPN and network proxy (automatic)

Comment: No, he means edit the configuration for the VM itself from the Virtualization Platform - the software that allowed you to create the VM itself, not from within the VM.  Without knowing which method you're using to *virtualize* Ubuntu, we can't really give you the exact methodology to do this.

Comment: OK - I used VMWare Workstation (12).  The Network card is set to connect at power on using NAT

Comment: any more info required?